# Ftp'ed .net application does not run (but runs when xcopied)

Tags: .net

I am stumped.  Faulty scenario is as follows:

a) I built a .net application on       machine1.    b) Using FTP (FileZilla     server & xp in built ftp client) I       copy the application + dlls to       machine2.    c) I try to launch that     application on machine2.    d)       Application does not give any errors     but quits immediately.  Nothing in       logged in event viewer or anywhere       else.

Wierdly, the following works.

a) Build .net app on machine1
   b) xcopying the exe folder to a shared location and then xcopy to machine2 
   c) launch the application on machine2.
   d) Application launches and works as expected.

I am not sure what I am missing.

a) Same thing happenned with 2 different machines
   b) A different user is NOT running into these issues, i.e, he can ftp and run the app successfully.

Is there any .net CAS coming into picture.  This is a .Net 4.0 application.  Any suggestions on how else to debug.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "binary" option in the FTP client.  Otherwise it's going to do funny things during the transfer (like turn every LF into CR/LF [or vice-versa, I don't remember]).

Comment: Setting type binary seems to have fixed it. Thanks a lot for your help.